# Long running Silverlight app losing connectivity via Client Object Model after a while?

Tags: client-object-model, sharepoint-online, silverlight

I have a Silverlight 5 app hosted in SharePoint **Online**, which asks the users 72 questions and right at the end writes their answers to some SharePoint lists.

When I trialled it with 8 users, the first four to finish had their results save to the list fine. The last four to finish didn't get their results saved.

All users had CONTRIBUTE access to the site in question.

I am thinking that somehow, the apps access to SharePoint via the Client Object model has timed out with the users who took longer to complete the test. Is this likely?

If that is the problem, are there any known solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Set the timeout to -1, this should prevent it.

```
context.RequestTimeout = -1
```

You can also set

```
KeepAlive = true;
```

And also there are more options in

```
SPWebApplication.ClientCallableSettings
```

Depends on your code as to why exactly but those are the places to prevent it.

Comment: Thanks Hugh. But option 1 doesn't seem to help. Option 2 doesn't seem to be valid, and I can't figure out how to implement option 3.

Comment: KeepAlive is on the spweb I think, and 3, there are a bunch of options in that name space you can use.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to add any reference (Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration?) that will recognise SPWeb or SPWebApplication. Any ideas where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Still no joy with this. Can anyone help? Thanks.